# Is there a generally unbiased estimator for the quantiles of a distribution?

Tags: statistics, median, quantile

1) Is there a generally unbiased estimator for the quantiles of a distribution?

If not - I would be glad for an explanation (proof?) of why not.

2) Also (if not), is there a specific family of distributions for which there is an unbiased estimator for their quantiles?

3) And lastly, is the median a special case for the general rule? (for example, is there a general unbiased estimator for the median?)

Comment: There are some obvious guesses here, namely the sample quantiles. You could try to calculate the expected value of these in some special cases for intuition.

Comment: Do you want a mean-unbiased estimator or median-unbiased estimator?

Comment: @A.S. - I wish the mean-unbiased estimator

Comment: @Ian - There are many definitions of sample quantiles. You need to specify which one you mean. That is why I asked if there is a general known solution (or specific known cases)

Comment: Then I'm pretty sure it doesn't exist (non-asymptotically) even for the median, unless distribution is symmetric since mean and median are too different of metrics. Consider sample of 3 points. You can't define an estimator of the median based on them that is unbiased.